# Cross referencing data sets to replace label for each observation (word based) in python

Tags: python, database, validation

I am attempting to compare results from the UK 2016 EU referendum results and the 2015 General Election. The data however is not consistent as the general election was separated by constituencies and the referendum by broader voting areas, i.e. the constituencies are subsets of the referendum regions.

General election 2015 data(csv): https://data.london.gov.uk/dataset/general-election-results-2015/resource/f1199bdc-922a-4aa5-a1b6-25e5b6c0ca3d

To compare the two I have the data 'regionmatch' that groups the constituencies into the referendum regions:

http://geoportal.statistics.gov.uk/datasets/68e5324bd26a4cacba349b4e8e4bc80b_0?uiTab=table

In this data, 'PCON14NM' are then the 'Constituencies', i.e. our General Election regions, and 'LAD14NM' are the broader regions from our referendum results.

I would like to change each the general election constituency labels to the corresponding broader regions.

My thoughts have been towards creating a loop that goes through each constituency cell and changes it to the corresponding referendum regions but have yet to find anything that is able to do this.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated or a nudge in the right direction.

Thank you

Comment: you can always re-invent the wheel; that is write your own code that would do this by parsing the files as if they where text files, store the data in lists and work with them and so on. However, there are many modules that can make your life easier like the `pandas` module. Take a look, write some code and come back for help if required.